Strategy to win at Codenames
Codenames Rules
Skip, if you already know Codenames.
There are two teams, each team consists of one caller and one guesser. In the middle of the table, a $5\times5$ grid is laid out, consisting of words. Both callers have a card that only they can see that specifies , which words are team A's (7), which are team B's (8, but first move) and which are neutral (the rest). The goal is for the guessers to guess all words of their team. Each turn, the caller can say a single word $W$ and the number of words $n$ that are connected to that hint. Once a guesss is locked in, the word is revealed. If it is correct, the guesser may continue, if it is wrong, the other teams turn starts. The guesser may guess $<n$ words.
Motivation
We play this often against another couple and want to convince them that we are more on each others wavelength than them. A good caller can do 3 consistently.
Goal
Develop a strategy that wins in two turns. More specific:

Come up with a procedure that uniquely identifies the words using the two communications $(W_1, n_1)$ and $(W_2, n_2)$.
$n_k$ must be smaller or equal than the remaining number of words of our team
$W_k$ must be a valid word/term
It must be doable with minimal memorization. Clearly mapping words to all possible positions would be a solution, just not a feasible one.

What we have considered so far: Compressed Row Strorage
(See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format))
We can use a binary classification of our words (1: our word, 0: not our word) to reduce the problem to having to transfer
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1&0&1\\
0&1&0&0&1\\
1&0&1&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
in two words. To further simplify it, we can use CRS (or CCS) to compress the matrix. As the matrix is binary, we can even drop the $\texttt{vals}$ vector (it would be $(1,1,1,1,\dots)^T$).
The remaining two vectors consisting of numbers from 0 to 4 are the problem here. We don't know how to transfer those. Our idea: There are five vowels, so creating a word that has the corresponding vowels in order would be great. But generating a word for every possible vector seems hard. Imagine the mapping would be:
$$
0\mapsto a\\
1\mapsto e\\
2\mapsto  i\\
3\mapsto o\\
4\mapsto u
$$, then the vector $(1,1,1,0,2,3,0)$ would become "representational".
This works for $\texttt{colInd}$, but not for $\texttt{rowInd}$, as this one will have values ranging from 0 to 8.
Any help is appreciated in winning the couples contest! Feel free to ask for clarifications.

You do know there's a rule in Codenames that clues must be semantic, right?

Can you define what "valid word" means for you? You can argue great-great-great-...-grandparent is a well-defined vaild a word. If you write the 5x5 matrix as a 25 digit binary string and use its numerical value to determine the number of "great" used in the word (you might need some patience to communicate this word), you have a 1-to-1-mapping from boards to words in only one clue.

As deus points out, this question is really asking how best to cheat at codenames, which is unlikely to go unnoticed by the opponents. I think it might be better phrased as more of a hypothetical question.

this sounds like a really convoluted way to lose a pair of friends

@Deusovi Well, yes, but that is merely a technicality in the couples contest ;-)

@PattuX Actually, one can just split it into two blocks of 12 and 13 each and say the number straight up for each block.

@juicifer https://xkcd.com/866/

As Deusovi mentioned in a comment above, this strategy is actually illegal in codenames, because the clues must be semantically related to the words being guessed.
That being said, if you want to cheat, here's how I would go about it:
Pre-arrange a mapping of card positions to letters in the alphabet.  The simplest would be
A B C D E
F G H I J
K L M N O
P R S T U
V W X Y Z

but you can choose something different if you want to be more sneaky.  (I left out Q because of its need to be tied to U in most words.)
Your team's words will correspond to seven or eight letters of the alphabet.
You come up with a word that contains as many of these letters as you can.  If the word starts with a consonant, vowels are ignored and only the consonants are guessed.  If the word starts with a vowel, all letters are considered. Repeated letters are ignored.  Any letters after the length given in the clue are ignored.
It should be achievable to come up with words that let you win in 2 rounds.  In some rare cases you might require 3 rounds, but there could be ways to mitigate that as well (see below).
If you get stuck, you can also take advantage of neutral cards and the "extra guess" rule, and stick a "neutral" letter in the middle of the word.
Example:
Your team's cards correspond to A C D T U V W X.
The neutral cards are E F J L N O P S Z

For your first clue, you say EXECUTABLE, 5 (for X C U T A).  This starts with a vowel, so your partner guesses the card position corresponding to E. That is neutral, so they have to stop.  But they now know that they should guess the next 5 unique letters in that word.  The B and L are ignored, because the clue only said to use 5 letters.
For the next clue, you say WAVED, 7.  It starts with a consonant, so vowels are ignored.  Your partner guesses W, V, and D.  Then they use what they know from the previous clue to guess X, C, U, and T.  They use the extra guess to guess A, and you have won.

This particular example adds drama and suspense, because after apparently completely failing at the first clue, you get to pull out a win on the second turn.
There should be enough flexibility in this strategy (using the neutrals where necessary) to be able to finish with only two clues in most cases.  If you get a really difficult batch of letters, it might require 3 clues, but you could always have another strategy like "if the first word has more than 8 letters, it means the grid has been rotated 180°."
Most of the uncommon letters will become much more common letters if you rotate the grid:

A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P R S T U V W X Y Z
Z Y X W V U T S R P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A

So if you ended up with something like J K U V W X Y Z as your letter set, you could invert the grid and have A B C D E F O P instead.

I suspect that this can't be executed in 2 rounds with valid words on most boards.

@kagami Have you tried?  I randomly generated letters for the team cards and neutrals for two separate games, and managed to find two-round solutions for both of them.  With the added option above of rotating the grid to swap the alphabet, I think it will be easier than you think.

I did, using the card in Tom's answer. Red needs BFGIJTVYZ, which looks pretty hard. I haven't checked with a computer, but I seriously doubt there's a solution. I think some alphabet rotation is necessary in general, but makes it very very difficult to imagine executing live.

It is worth pointing  out that blue is pretty easy for that same card, CHUCKLE and WHELP work without requiring a mistake. Still took me a while to do in my head just because mapping the grid to the letters is a surprisingly difficult memory load, even though I do these wordy puzzly sorts of things all the time.

@kagami By using the strategy of rotating the grid, you end up with ABEGPRTUY, which is much easier.  I found (UTTERABLE, 6) and (PIGGY, 3) in a matter of minutes, which would mesh with the suggested rule above of rotating the grid if the first word is more than 8 letters.

Then you're better than I am at this kind of thing! I tried with a couple more cards, and couldn't work out answers in my head in a time frame that would be reasonable in a live game. Did you find that solution within a few minutes without the aid of a computer and without writing down the letters?

@kagami I did it in about 5-10 minutes, without a computer, but I did write down the letters.  I guess even 5-10 minutes would be pretty long for a turn in Codenames, though...

The game comes with 40 of these key cards:

You and your partner should memorize these 40 patterns.
These key cards can be oriented in 4 ways, so there are 160 total configurations.
Just assign a word to each configuration. Then you can always win on the first turn.

You only need 80 words; the color of the card is public knowledge.

@Accumulation but you can rotate the card your times.

You only need 24 bits, since the last one can be inferred (you know how many 1s there are). You can encode 4 bits each in how long it takes to give the clue and the number. Then you only need 4 bits in each clue. Choosing between the first four vowel is 2 bits each, so you can encode the bits in two vowels. So for instance, with the string 001010100110100110000000, you break it down into 0010 1010 0110 1001 1000 0000. So you wait 2 seconds to give the clue, the clue is a word with two e's, and then you wait 6 second before giving the number.
Or you can then just convert the binary string to decimal and give that as your number. Using the example of  001010100110100110000000 again, you say "Cheating, 2779520". You don't even need to convert to decimal, you could just list the string out as a number.

So if your string starts with 0001 1101, you have 1 second to come up with a word containing I and A.  Can you do it?

The Kwyjibo approach
Nonsense words are still technically words, and there's no requirement that clues must be found in a dictionary. Simply encode the 25 cards with letters A-Y in some predetermined arrangement, and state your clue as the word made up of your team's cards' letters. You're allowed to spell your clue out, so there should be no misinterpretation.
"The clue is 'bufkloksiv', 8. That's spelled B-F-K-L-O-Q-S-V."
This is of course not legal, since the clue has nothing to do with the semantic meaning of the words you're cluing.

My proposal is very similar to what is suggested in the question, but I'm keeping it fleshed out so that it works as a stand-alone answer. The goal is to identify all targets on turn 2, whether there be 9 going first, or 8 going second. In examples, I'll assume 9.
I. Represent the board by the distance between targets, reading left to right, top to bottom (or whatever ordering you and your partner agree upon to obfuscate the strategy). I.e. the following board:
1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 0

is 1, 2, 4, 2, 6, 2, 1, 2, 4
Your clue words will represent these numbers with their vowels, A=1, E=2, I=3, O=4, U=5, Y=6.
II. Your first clue will try to hit as many of these as possible in a valid word, in order, with consonants to be ignored by your partner. Your first clue is followed by a number, which will also be one of your distances. If there's a 7+, you have to use the number for that. Your partner will guess as if nothing is odd; they'll pick the most semantically related word and probably be wrong. Here you afford yourself the option to play normally if the clue-giver can't figure out a pair of winning words; your partner will know you've called off the strategy if the semantically related words are correct.
III. Your second word will attempt to finish the pattern. Here your number has to be the number of targets remaining, or one less than that. If you and your partner are ok with a bit of extra complication in exchange for flexibility, you can use this bit of freedom to signal an alternative ordering. E.g. with 9 targets, 9 means left to right, top to bottom, while 8 means top to bottom, left to right. This modification would be necessary for any board that has a large gap between targets near the beginning of the sequence.
IV. Your partner sweeps the board.
As an example, the above board might use the following clues:
ANTELOPE 6
EASTERNMOST 9
In the card from Tom's answer, which is
0 R B 0 B
R R B R R
B B 0 0 0
B 0 X R B
R B 0 R R

Red could use clues: VENTROLATERAL 9, VERTICAL 9 (possible live, albeit impressive)
Blue could use clues: SCIENTIFIC 1, OBOE 9 (pretty easy)
This strategy still requires a bit of quick thinking and word skill on the part of the clue-giver, but should be achievable in a live game, easy to execute for the partner, and will certainly win in spectacular fashion.

This runs the risk of your first guess hitting the "assassin" and losing the game.
